# Django filter model based on max date

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have a model Drugs with following entries :

```
id  location  num  date         country
1   UC        ABC  2021-03-26   ZAF
2   UC        DEF  2021-03-26   ZAF       # line to retrieve with filter
3   UC        ABC  2021-09-06   ZAF       # line to retrieve with filter
```

I want to select record based on max date for a combinaison loc - num - date

for example, in the test case above, I want to only return the laste 2 records as id 3 is more recent than id 1

Comment: you want to retrieve 2 records,with max date ?

Comment: in example above, there are 2 lines (1 and 3) with UC / ABC and I want to retrieve the line with max date (line 3)

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Max

result = Drug.objects.values('location','num').annotate(max_date=Max('date')).order_by()
```

Explanation :

From the `Drug` table, `group` the rows by `location` and `num` (so row1 and row3 will be grouped together, in your example), then get record with `Max('date')`

Comment: the example above is just an 'extract' I can not use slice in my case

Comment: Please generalize your question, what finally you want to retrieve

Comment: Whats your logic for retrieval, you can tell in plain english ?

Comment: You want to retrieve all record, but if loc-num clash then maxdate ?

Comment: yes I want to filter 'duplicate' on loc-num and get the latest

Comment: no, it retrieve 2 lines and just replace the date with the max date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236805/discussion-between-prakhar-and-mereva).